# What is the operator %>% in R?

Tags: r

Apologies for the simple question. I'm learning R, and Stack Overflow has been a valuable resource.

What is the operator %>% used for in R? I see it used in some answers, but it's not a term I can search for, here or in Google. It doesn't appear in ?Arithmetic.

Comment: Its from the package magrittr https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/magrittr.pdf
Start with this http://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/

Comment: It's unfortunately difficult to search for on SO.

Comment: Heck, "***R***" is difficult everywhere except places where you can search for `[R]` (like SO); only when I can include something like "CRAN" or "r-project" to a search engine am I confident it'll give me something relevant.